# How to find 'overlapping' values from an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Given two arrays of objects, how can I find all objects that contain an 'overlapping' value (e.g. price in this case)?

For example, given array A and array B, how can I find all objects where the "price" is either an exact match (e.g. 20, 30) or contained within this overlap (e.g. 20.45)?

```
var A = [
  { "id" : 1, "price" : 50, "quantity": 2 },
  { "id" : 2, "price" : 40, "quantity": 2 },
  { "id" : 3, "price" : 30, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 4, "price" : 20, "quantity": 2 }  // yes
];

var B = [
  { "id" : 5, "price" : 30, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 6, "price" : 20.45, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 7, "price" : 20, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 8, "price" : 10, "quantity": 2 },
  { "id" : 9, "price" : 5, "quantity": 2 }
];


// Goal
var C = [
  { "id" : 3, "price" : 30, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 4, "price" : 20, "quantity": 2 }  // yes
];
var D = [
  { "id" : 5, "price" : 30, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 6, "price" : 20.45, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
  { "id" : 7, "price" : 20, "quantity": 2 }, // yes
];
```

My goal is to keep them separated into their own arrays (C & D). But if the end result needs to be one combined array, that's okay. I can probably make that work too. Anything that works would make me happy right now.

I've tried Underscore's intersection. If A & B were simple arrays containing integers rather than objects, then intersection would work to find the exact matches (e.g. 30 & 30, 20 & 20), but it still wouldn't include 20.45, which I need as well. And, of course, I have an array of objects instead of simple arrays, which makes it a bit harder as well.

Comment: simple loop can do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we can assume that those arrays are sorted by price (if not, do so - see [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979256/1048572) and similar), and that `A` contains higher prices than `B` (if not, you'd need to invert the logic). Then just do:

```
var i = A.length - 1,
    j = 0,
    overlapMin = A[i].price,
    overlapMax = B[j].price;
while (A[i].price <= overlapMax) i--;
while (B[j].price >= overlapMin) j++;
var C = A.slice(i+1), // to end
    D = B.slice(0, j);
```

If you need better performance on a really huge set, you could use binary searches for the boundaries `i` and `j` as well.

Comment: That works! And looks very efficient. I am sorting them by price.I tried to click up vote, it wouldn't let me as an SO noob yet, and it came back as a -1. Not sure if that was me or it just updating the tally. Sorry about that if I accidentally did it trying to upvote. ;) WTH Stackoverflow?

Answer (score -1):

```
var C = [], D = [];
for (var i in A)
    for (var j in B)
        if (A[i].price > B[j].price-1 && A[i].price < B[j].price+1) {
             C.push(A[i]);
             D.push(B[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Hmm Something is slightly off. C & D end up with more objects than A & B. http://jsfiddle.net/R5vjN/

Comment: yea, there should be && not ||

Comment: [Do not use `for-in`-loops with arrays!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: That's darn close. Cool. The only problem is that it's adding one of the objects from A twice to C (`{"id":4,"price":20,"quantity":2}`). So I tried removing the objects after they're pushed onto C or D, but that kills the script. http://jsfiddle.net/tU4en/

Comment: What do those `+1` and `-1` after the prices do there?